# what's the principle of xamarin.ios remote simulator?

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios-simulator

xamarin.ios has a powerfull feature: mirror the ios simulator to windows.

I'd like to know how xamarin implements it.

when the mirrored simulator is showing in WIN, I can't find any `Simulator.app` process running in the MAC, so how does xamarin run it ? is there any public API for controlling the ios simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

> when the mirrored simulator is showing in WIN, I can't find any
>   Simulator.app process running in the MAC, so how does xamarin run it ?

The simulator is still running in the mac. The process is `com.apple.CoreSimlutor.CoreSimlutorService`, I find some related processes about simulator when run the simulator on Windows.

And I think the mirrored simulator is showing in WIN is using the technology like a remote desktop. Like VNC. (Just my own thinking, not the official answer)

Here is the picture:

[image: Simulator process2]

[image: Simulator]

[image: Simulator process]

Comment: thanks~ is there any document about `com.apple.CoreSimlutor.CoreSimlutorService`? how could we start an offscreen simulator and control its behaviour?

Comment: @fatfatson Well, I don't know the detailed principle of how the simulator works in Windows. What I can confirm is that the simulator is running in the mac and the windows side is using the technology like remote-control. I will ask the people in relevant team and update you if I get anything. I think it's similar like how vnc works.

Comment: thank you very much! I understand the vnc part, but how to control a simulator programmatically is still a puzzle and interesting for me.